# How to save and print the high score into the next scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Hey guys im looking for some help. I'm new making games and stuff so it's a little difficult for me. Im trying to save the score and print it into my GameOverScene.swift from the GameScene.swift, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options might be:

1. Save highscore in app delegate. I gameover scene print it from appDelegate.
2. Save highscore in NSUserDefault. then in GameOverScene show it form there.
3. Create a property in GameOverScene and while navigating to GameOverSecne from GameScene set that property.

Here is some tutorial on [NSUserDefault](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/), [Passing data between ViewControllers](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/).

Comment: Yes, the NSUserDefault one. Thank you